# There is any open source for mnemonic (recovery) phrase can be used in react project?

Tags: blockchain, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, react

I want to know how to implement 12 words or 24 words mnemonic(recovery) phrase screen as "Create Wallet" part in the ethereum, ERC20 token wallet project built with React Native like as coinomi wallet.
Teach me any open or paid source to refer, blog, or sample code.